# What's the exact meaning of 'skim off the top'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw this scene from 'The Godfather' (part 1), where the expression 'skim off the top' was used:

> Michael: The Corleone family wants to buy you out.
> Mike: The Corleone family wants to buy me out? No, I buy you out, you don't buy me out.
> Michael: Your casino loses money. Maybe we can do better.
> Mike: you think I'm skimming off the top, Mike?
> Michael:  You're unlucky.

I didn't understand the expression "skim off the top", so I looked it up.
According to Wikipedia, skimming off the top is: "taking cash "off the top" of the daily receipts of a business".

It didn't make sense to me, because in the scene Mike says this expression as a comeback to Michael saying "Your casino loses money", and if you take money of the daily receipts of your business, meaning, you don't report to the government about part of your money, it doesn't mean you necessarily loses money.

I looked up at Stack Exchange English, but the explanation there didn't make sense either:

> "skimming off the top" is short for "skimming cream off the top of milk". The cream is the most valuable part (in terms of calories and essential vitamins) of milk.

In most businesses, the profits are a small percentage of the money that passes through the business. If an embezzler takes a small percentage of the money that passes through, they can take all of the profits. As a side benefit, unprofitable businesses don't have any taxable income.

It is a crime to embezzle, and it is a crime to commit tax-fraud. But this context is a conversation between criminals, who have committed much worse crimes than embezzlement and tax-fraud.

As a hypothetical example:

Suppose $ 10,000,000 is bet on roulette.
Suppose the casino wins $ 526,000 of that money.
Suppose the casino has $ 300,000 of operating expenses (salaries, utilities, advertising, et cetera) to attract the betters who made those bets.
Suppose the casino has $ 100,000 of depreciation of the buildings and equipment used to attract those betters.
Suppose the casino spends $ 100,000 in interest (and other financing costs) to repay the people who provided the money for the buildings and equipment.
Suppose half the taxable income needs to be paid as income taxes.
Then there should be a net profit of $ 13,000.

Now suppose that Moe "skims" one-half of one percent of the $ 10,000,000 of bets. Instead of a net profit of $ 13,000, there will be a net loss of $ 24,000. The casino will not be able to afford to fix everything that wears out, and will deteriorate. (And Moe will probably not pay taxes on this $ 50,000.)"

According to this explanation, If you skim off the top, you don't report about part of your money, and therefore, can't afford to fix everything that wears out, meaning-If you report to the government you earned less and pay less taxes, you have less money. It doesn't make any sense to me, because If you pay less taxes you're supposed to have more money.

In this context, I think that this expression must have been related to Mike loses money, and can't be related to him earning money.
so, what's the exact definition of the expression 'skim off the top' which can be suited to that context?

Comment: There is a Movies and TV Stack Exchange where you can ask for explanations of the plot of a film.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage....Your question is over-broad, and some users are voting as Primarily-Opinion-Based. In fact, I could cast the final VTC,.  Consider restricting your question to make it more on-topic. I did not downvote.

Answer (score 3):

It means that Moe Greene was taking the profits of the casino for himself and thus the casino ended up losing money. The negative implication here is nothing to do with taxes or the illegality of the act. According to the Godfather wiki, [Moe Greene is based on Bugsy Siegel](https://godfather.fandom.com/wiki/Moe_Greene):

> Greene died on account of refusal to sell. Siegel had been installed by the Mafia to manage the Flamingo Casino due to his accounting reputation. When revenue was down in spite of the Flamingo being a hot destination in town, Mafia bosses began to suspect Siegel was **skimming profits**, and ordered his death.

Bugsy Siegel skimming of the top was a problem for the Mafia bosses he was working for. The line in the film can be a reference to that or it can suggest that Moe Greene was beholden to the people who financed his casino building and that it might have been tied to any profits, which he would have been distorting by "skimming off the top". By taking the money for himself, he would have been cheating others out of their share.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that it *is* analogous to skimming the cream off the top of the milk.

Yes, they're crims and do worse than embezzle. But if the firm from which you are embezzling is owned by the criminal organization, they're not exactly going to say "Oh, what does it matter, it's just a crime like any other, we're all criminals, bless his heart."

No, they are going to want their money back.

Comment: Yep, it's a metaphor for skimming cream off the top of milk, and other similar actions.